# How to get depth(h) value of area of an arc segment?

Tags: geometry, area

I would like to type ab excel formulation sheet, and i need to value of h as an input. I shared the formulation to calculate area of arc segment. Is there any way to re-type this formulation according to value of h? I mean that i need kind of h = 1/2....bla bla bla...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHoG4.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, the formula cannot be inverted analytically. You need to resort to numerical resolution. Use the Solver add-in.

Comment: Thank you Yves. It s really good starting point for me. I have no idea about how can i use solver add-in. But, i will research it and try. Thank you.